# Updating apns credentials in azure notification hubs causing error in portal

Tags: azure

I'm trying to update the existing APNS Credential for my Azure notification hub.

Regardless if I try to upload a new certificate or click "Delete Credential" I get the same error:

> Error updating notification hub
>
> {"error":{"message":"Object reference
> not set to an instance of an object.","code":"InternalServerError"}}

If I check the developer console in the browser, there's a PATCH request made, where the only parameter is `pnsCredential: null`.

I've tried multiple browsers and computers with same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your edit, it is correct: this was a **transient issue** in the Notification Hubs creation. This is now resolved and we are not expecting that specific issue to happen again.

Thanks, Karl

Answer (score 0):

Updating for anyone else who may find this.

This seems to have been an issue on Azure Portal. It has since been resolved and now works as expected, without any further action on my end.

I did report it to @AzureSupport but have not heard of any action taken by them, so not sure if that is why it was resolved.